# Multiline capture regex fails if ungreedy

Tags: regex

I would like to retrieve data from an xml file. I use for instance a regexp like this one:

```
/
<OVERLAYLINKPROJECT(?:.|\s)+
<OUTPUT
/xU
```

Here's an extract of my xml file:

```
<OVERLAYLINKPROJECT id='0773C138' parent_id='007285A0' ovl_id='0x4b' run_address='0x9022a' run_size='0x450' live_address='0x40c111' live_size='0x678' >
<FILE_NAME><![CDATA[xxx.ovl]]></FILE_NAME>
<OUTPUT_SECTIONS>
<OUTPUT_SECTION id='0773C138' name='xxxx' type='SHT_PROGBITS' start_address='0x9022a' word_size='0x450' word_size_unmapped='0x0' in_overlay='' >
<INPUT_SECTIONS>
<INPUT_SECTION id='0580D5B0' name='yyyy' start_address='0x9022b' size='0x44f' element_at='0x0' >
```

The regex doesn't work without the ungreedy modificator `U`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, surprisingly enough, [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

You used `(?:.|\s)`, presumably because `.` doesn't match newlines, and your input contains them. However, `\s` also matches other whitespace which can also be matched by `.`.

If you don't use the ungreedy modifier, `(?:.|\s)+` first matches the entire string after `<OVERLAYLINKPROJECT` and then backtracks to see where `<OUTPUT` can first be matched. At each and every space, it needs to try all the alternatives between matching it with `.` or matching it with `\s` before it can be sure that neither lead to a valid match.

There are 14 spaces in that part of the string. Each one has to be checked in every possible combination with all the other ones, which leads to 14! (= 87178291200) permutations that all have to be checked. That takes a while (or the regex engine times out).

When you use the ungreedy modifier, the regex engine steps through the match one character at a time, "marking" each whitespace for later evaluation in case the match fails - but it succeeds as soon as `<OUTPUT` is encountered. That's why it matches much faster. It will still fail catastrophically if the input string does *not* contain `<OUTPUT` at all - because in that case, the regex engine needs to revisit all the spaces and try the different permutations in the vain hope of finding a match that way.

Use the `/s` modifier instead to allow the dot to match newlines:

```
/
<OVERLAYLINKPROJECT.+
<OUTPUT
/xs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<OVERLAYLINKPROJECT(?:.|\s)+?<OUTPUT
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/bW3aR1/1

The problem with your regex is catastrophic backtracking as explained by Tim.